# Google Sheets API Failing with 500

Tags: google-sheets-api

I made this URL public a few years ago as a way to retrieve data. It was working yesterday. Today my site is crashing as it relies on this data, but google is now returning a 500 error if I try to retrieve it programmatically (through axios).

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DLAVN3q758sPohCFeZlVSVRZKXzEser1SIsQnH2mvrw/ogwtdyp/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json

I have also created a code sandobox with react to demonstrate: https://codesandbox.io/embed/xjmy9vl2z4

However, I am still able to view the response in the browser if I am logged in.

Did google recently change their API so that it is no longer possible to retrieve data this way? Is there a way to configure my axios request in such a way to continue retrieving this data?

UPDATE:

Issue is being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284

According to the support team: "The engineering team believes they have located the source of the problem and are rolling back to a previous build in order to resolve issue. Please stand by."

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284#comment109

UPDATE:

It seems like the issue has been resolved by rolling back to a previous build. I am no longer experiencing these issues. The link above, and the code sandbox example are both functioning. Reading the forum, it seems like others are also no longer experiencing issues. If you are still experiencing issues, I would encourage opening another (perhaps more specific) post or issue.

Comment: Recently, I noticed that when I access to ``https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/...`` of the public Spreadsheet, ``Internal Error`` is returned. I'm not sure whether this is a temporal situation. So as a workaround, I shared the Spreadsheet as only view. And when the old endpoint is still the error, I used the following endpoint. ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{fileId}/gviz/tq?gid={sheetId}&tqx=out:json`` and ``tqx=out:csv``. By this, I can confirm that the values can be retrieved from Spreadsheet. But I'm not sure whether this is what you want, so I posted this as a comment.

Comment: I tested, and it seems like I can retrieve the values if I am logged in, but I'm still unable to retrieve from an unauthenticated http request. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Seems like there are others experiencing a similar issue on the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you try to share the Spreadsheet and use the endpoint of ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{fileId}/gviz/tq?gid={sheetId}&tqx=out:json``? By sharing the Spreadsheet, you can retrieve the values from the endpoint. And thank you for the additional information. I could know that this issue also occurs at other users.

Comment: Your english is great. Following up on the google issue, it seems like this might be an issue on their end. I did confirm that the spreadsheet is set to share. I also tested the endpoint you suggested, and it has the same issue. Now that the issue is approaching almost 200 stars on their issue tracker, I think I might wait to see if the google issue is resolved/answered before I continue. It seems like many people are having this issue, so a work-around may not be necessary.

Comment: Seems like the team is on it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284#comment82    "Thank you all for reporting this issue. I've been able to reproduce the error and have raised the issue with the engineering team. At the time there are no known workaround."

Comment: "The engineering team believes they have located the source of the problem and are rolling back to a previous build in order to resolve issue. Please stand by."

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284#comment109